# Common navbar for all viewController with same action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am newbie in iOS.
I want to set navbar that display on all screens and managed by Navigation Controller and it calls the same action.

Comment: Create your custom navigation controller, set up its behaviour and use it through out application.

Comment: yes that i already tried, but not able to set title image from navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about having some `UIViewController`'s add the same `UINavigationItem`'s, then I would create a super class that adds the `UINavigationitem`'s  and have the `UIViewControllers`'s be a subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to set image in title.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;
```

Or create a custom method and invoke it in each controller in order to set different title logo in every controller.